# Android TabLayout custom indicator width

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-tablayout

I want to reduce width of indicator - for example, make it's width not whole tab width, but 1/2 of tab width.
That's all I need to do, so I don't want to download some custom library and search where I can do this.

Is it a way to do this or I should write such view by myself?

Comment: this answer working for me very well
https://stackoverflow.com/a/52514798/9368693

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this.

```
public void setIndicator (TabLayout tabs,int leftDip,int rightDip){  
   Class<?> tabLayout = tabs.getClass();  
   Field tabStrip = null;  
   try {  
       tabStrip = tabLayout.getDeclaredField("mTabStrip");  
   } catch (NoSuchFieldException e) {  
       e.printStackTrace();  
   }  

   tabStrip.setAccessible(true);  
   LinearLayout llTab = null;  
   try {  
       llTab = (LinearLayout) tabStrip.get(tabs);  
   } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {  
       e.printStackTrace();  
   }  

   int left = (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, leftDip, Resources.getSystem().getDisplayMetrics());  
   int right = (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, rightDip, Resources.getSystem().getDisplayMetrics());  

   for (int i = 0; i < llTab.getChildCount(); i++) {  
       View child = llTab.getChildAt(i);  
       child.setPadding(0, 0, 0, 0);  
       LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(0, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 1);  
       params.leftMargin = left;  
       params.rightMargin = right;  
       child.setLayoutParams(params);  
       child.invalidate();  
   }  
}
```

And then

```
tab.post(new Runnable() {  
       @Override  
       public void run() {  
           setIndicator(tab,60,60);  
       }  
});
```

**My modification w/o reflection (custom view should be set!).**

```
for (int i = 0; i < tabs.getTabCount(); i++) {
    TabLayout.Tab tab = tabs.getTabAt(i);
    if (tab != null) {
        View customView = tab.getCustomView();
        if (customView != null) {
            View targetViewToApplyMargin = (View) customView.getParent();
            ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams layoutParams = (ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams) targetViewToApplyMargin.getLayoutParams();

            layoutParams.rightMargin = totalTabMargin;
                    targetViewToApplyMargin.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I've modified your answer a bit (with custom view, without reflection). But direction was definitely correct!

Comment: Thanks to your modification.I will try it tomorrow.@GoltsevEugene

Comment: gre8-> Works fine for me. Thanks.

Comment: @GoltsevEugene May I know how do you set the custom view and what do you set it to?

Comment: yourTabs.getTabAt(tabIndex).setCustomView(yourView).

Comment: @GoltsevEugene What is the value of 'totalTabMargin' varibale?

Comment: @codeWorm, actually, its calculated margin; in my case it is tab width - desired indicator width, but you might calculate it in some other way.

Answer (score 26):

if a tab indicator with a fixed size is what you want, to achieve you can create an indicator shape with a fixed size by drawable:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:gravity="center">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="@color/colorAccent" />
            <corners
                android:topLeftRadius="2dp"
                android:topRightRadius="2dp" />
            <size
                android:width="16dp"
                android:height="2dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

Then on the TabLayout, you can then just set the tab indicator drawable.
at the same time, you also have to set the `tabIndicatorColor`

```
 app:tabIndicatorColor="@color/tabIndicatorColor"
 app:tabIndicator="@drawable/tab_indicator"
```

Because the drawable itself centers the shape inside its bounds, the indicator will have a fixed size.

if you want the indicator to match the width of the label, you can remove the tabIndicator `android:gravity`.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="@color/colorAccent" />
            <corners
                radius="2dp" />
            <size
                android:width="16dp"
                android:height="2dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

Comment: This the cleanest solution! I had solved with a 9-patch PNG, but this one is surely better. I had tried a similar solution but was missing that the default `gravity` value is `fill`...

Answer (score 15):

For anyone that ends up on this issue, I found a simple solution with vector drawables for a ~90% of the tab width indicator:

ic_tab_indicator_24dp:

```
<vector
android:height="24dp"
android:width="24dp"
android:viewportHeight="24.0"
android:viewportWidth="24.0"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<path
    android:strokeWidth="4"
    android:fillColor="@android:color/white"
    android:pathData="M2,0 L22,0 L22,24 L2,24 z"/>
```

And then set tabIndicator in the layout:

```
app:tabIndicator="@drawable/ic_tab_indicator_24dp"
```

Or in styles.xml:

```
<item name="tabIndicator">@drawable/ic_tab_indicator_24dp</item>
```

[image: Example]

**Edit:** As my solution is getting attention, I'd add that you can play with the width just modifying the pathData ("M2,0 L22,0 L22,24 L2,24 z") changing 2 and 22 values. The amount added to 2 should be subtracted from 22. i.e.: "M4,0 L20,0 L20,24 L4,24 z" or "M6,0 L18,0 L18,24 L6,24 z"...

Comment: This logic is awesome!

Answer (score 3):

Tried all those solutions,but not satisfied, and finally I found a solution myself, we just need to modify the indicatorLeft and indicatorRight fileds of SlidingTabIndicator, extends the tablayout and call setIndicaotrWidth() when need, for example:

`setIndicatorWidth(70);`

The whole code:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.util.TypedValue;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewTreeObserver;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout;

import java.lang.reflect.Field;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;

public class TabLayoutEx extends TabLayout {

    public TabLayoutEx(Context context) {
        this(context, null);
    }

    public TabLayoutEx(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        this(context, attrs, 0);
    }

    public TabLayoutEx(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
        init(attrs);
    }

    private void init(AttributeSet attrs) {
        setTabIndicatorFullWidth(false);
        setIndicatorWidth(70);
    }



    private class DefPreDrawListener implements ViewTreeObserver.OnPreDrawListener {

        private LinearLayout tabStrip = null;
        private int tabWidth;
        private Field fieldLeft;
        private Field fieldRight;

        public void setTabStrip(LinearLayout tabStrip, int width) {
            try {
                this.tabStrip = tabStrip;
                this.tabWidth = width;
                Class cls = tabStrip.getClass();
                fieldLeft = cls.getDeclaredField("indicatorLeft");
                fieldLeft.setAccessible(true);
                fieldRight = cls.getDeclaredField("indicatorRight");
                fieldRight.setAccessible(true);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onPreDraw() {
            try {
                if (tabWidth > 0) {
                    int left = fieldLeft.getInt(this.tabStrip);
                    int right = fieldRight.getInt(this.tabStrip);
                    //根据目标宽度及现在的宽度调整为合适的left和right
                    int diff = right - left - tabWidth;
                    left = left + diff / 2;
                    right = right - diff / 2;
                    fieldLeft.setInt(this.tabStrip, left);
                    fieldRight.setInt(this.tabStrip, right);
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return true;
        }
    }

    private DefPreDrawListener defPreDrawListener = new DefPreDrawListener();

    public void setIndicatorWidth(int widthDp) {
        Class<?> tabLayout = TabLayout.class;
        Field tabStrip = null;
        try {
            tabStrip = tabLayout.getDeclaredField("slidingTabIndicator");
            tabStrip.setAccessible(true);
            LinearLayout tabIndicator = (LinearLayout) tabStrip.get(this);
            int width = (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, widthDp, Resources.getSystem().getDisplayMetrics());
            //avoid add preDrawListener multi times
            tabIndicator.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnPreDrawListener(defPreDrawListener);
            tabIndicator.getViewTreeObserver().addOnPreDrawListener(defPreDrawListener);
            defPreDrawListener.setTabStrip(tabIndicator, width);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: after using this code, tab indicator width is located at center but i want it left side, want its size half of the text from last side.. then what to do ?

Answer (score 1):

you could copy TabLayout, and modify the logic of calculating the width of Indicator. See updateIndicatorPosition() and animateIndicatorToPosition(). 
A simple demo https://github.com/xybean/CustomTabLayout

Comment: It looks more like recommendation but not full answer. Can you provide the example of implementation of your idea? It would be great if you add some details. Thank you!

Comment: What ideally I tried to do is to copy all those classes - ViewPager, TabLayout etc. to have fully customizable behaviour. The problem is that when copied, there are a lot of private/native fields which I cannot import into the project. Moreover, all these classes have very strong connections to other classes in support package. So it's was really hard for me to do that.

Comment: @GoltsevEugene Just copy TabLayout.

Comment: @Yazon2006 I upload a demo to github see https://github.com/xybean/CustomTabLayout