# I'm using material Design Fragment tabs layout

Tags: android, performance, android-layout, android-fragments

Currently my problem is how to increase the Images width and height?
Below I mentioned the Image for tab layout fragment

Please anyone help me.

[image]

Comment: u can do it by using custom views in the tab

Comment: what is your icon size ?

Comment: if you don't mine give me sample code for custom views..@Manoj Kumar

Comment: my icon size is 64*64  - SahadevRajput

Comment: check out this tuts for your problem https://www.androidhive.info/2015/09/android-material-design-working-with-tabs/

Comment: Thanks.@Omi. I'm using Androidhive code but Image size was not changed

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

**1.`TabLayout` 's width**

```
public void setIndicator (TabLayout tabs,int leftDip,int rightDip){  
   Class<?> tabLayout = tabs.getClass();  
   Field tabStrip = null;  
   try {  
       tabStrip = tabLayout.getDeclaredField("mTabStrip");  
   } catch (NoSuchFieldException e) {  
       e.printStackTrace();  
   }  

   tabStrip.setAccessible(true);  
   LinearLayout llTab = null;  
   try {  
       llTab = (LinearLayout) tabStrip.get(tabs);  
   } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {  
       e.printStackTrace();  
   }  

   int left = (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, leftDip, Resources.getSystem().getDisplayMetrics());  
   int right = (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, rightDip, Resources.getSystem().getDisplayMetrics());  

   for (int i = 0; i < llTab.getChildCount(); i++) {  
       View child = llTab.getChildAt(i);  
       child.setPadding(0, 0, 0, 0);  
       LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(0, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 1);  
       params.leftMargin = left;  
       params.rightMargin = right;  
       child.setLayoutParams(params);  
       child.invalidate();  
   }  
}
```

And then

```
tab.post(new Runnable() {  
       @Override  
       public void run() {  
           setIndicator(tab,60,60);  
       }  
});
```

**My modification w/o reflection (custom view should be set!).**

```
for (int i = 0; i < tabs.getTabCount(); i++) {
            TabLayout.Tab tab = tabs.getTabAt(i);
            if (tab != null) {
                View customView = tab.getCustomView();
                if (customView != null) {
                    View targetViewToApplyMargin = (View) customView.getParent();
                    ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams layoutParams = (ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams) targetViewToApplyMargin.getLayoutParams();

                    layoutParams.rightMargin = totalTabMargin;
                    targetViewToApplyMargin.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
                }
            }
 }
```

**2.`TabLayout` 's height**

```
 app:tabIndicatorHeight="10dp"
```

And java for setting height

```
 mTabLayout.setSelectedTabIndicatorHeight(10);
```

According to [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45715737/android-tablayout-custom-indicator-width/45715890#45715890)